# How to solve Simultaneous equation without numerical answers, e.g.finding points for a phase plane analysis.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Using

$$u\left( 1-u-av\right) =\dfrac {du} {dt}$$
$$cv\left( 1-bu-v\right) =\dfrac {dv} {dt}$$

Get to

$$\left( \overline {u},\overline {v}\right) =\left( \dfrac {1-a} {1-ab},\dfrac {1-b} {1-ab}\right) $$

What kind of things do you look for to solve simultainouly like this

Comment: Are you not sure what equations to set up (which Ross Millikan addressed), or are you not sure how to do the algebra to solve the equations for $\overline u$ and $\overline v$?

Comment: not sure how to get U and V.

Comment: There are no $U$ and $V$ in your problem.  Do you mean $u$ and $v$ or the overline versions?  Please be careful with symbols.  Different ones mean different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the overlines represent a stable solution.  In that case there is no change with time so you just set the derivatives to zero and solve the equations normally.

Added:  I will leave off the overlines to save typing.  You solve $$u(1-u-av)=0\\ 
 cv(1-bu-v)=0\\u=1-av\\1-bu-v=0\\1-b+abv-v=0\\
v=\frac {1-b}{1-ab}\\u=\frac {1-a}{1-ab}$$

Comment: could you show me in full. I'm fine with finding numerical steady states. This one is known as a co existence steady state, and i'm not sure how to get to it,

Comment: It's a steady-state solution in both variables. The lack of time-dependence to the solution guarantees that the solution given above is right, and there's really nothing else to say. @tutorz

Comment: @Ross Millikan  won't the 5th line give $1-b=v(ab+1)$  then dividing gives the denominator as $1+ab$. How does that become negative on line 6.

Comment: @Semiclassical:  you are right.  Thanks.  Fixed